# Change the chat background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this:

```
var chat_background = localStorage.getItem("chat_bg")
    var effective_background = undefined
    if(chat_background != undefined) {
        effective_background = chat_background
        $$("#chat-background").css("background", "rgb(" + chat_background + ")")
    }
    else {
        effective_background = app_config['chat_background']
        $$("#chat-background").css("background", "rgb(" + app_config['chat_background'] + ")")
    }
    [bg_red, bg_green, bg_blue] = chat_background.split(",")

    bg_color_temp = light_or_dark(bg_red, bg_green, bg_blue)

    if(last_background_temp != undefined && bg_color_temp != last_background_temp) {
        $("." + last_background_temp + "-timebox").removeClass(last_background_temp + "-timebox").addClass(bg_color_temp + "-timebox")
    }
    last_background_temp = bg_color_temp
    timebox_class = last_background_temp + '-timebox'
```

My two classes are:

```
.dark-timebox {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white !important;
    border: none !important;
}

.light-timebox {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.58);
    color:#a7a7a7 !important;
}
```

So I want to change my chats background, but when I use this code it works when I change the background but also I want to work it in default.
How can I do this?

Actually, if I do not change the chat background the code does not work. How can I fix that?

Comment: Why did you used `$$` instead of a single `$` ?

Comment: i use this to speed up my program running

Comment: @hossein, what?